# Symbolic on js File not working

Tags: windows-10, symlink

I am trying to make a symbolic link on a js file. It creates a symbolic link but shows the size as 0KB although it has data in it.

I am using this command
    mklink \d {link} {Target}
Can someone tell the command or any other approach?

Comment: The /d option creates a directory symbolic link.

Answer (score 0):

You can use unix command installed Cygwin, Gow, UnxUtils, GnuWin

```
ln -s source destination
```

PowerShell syntax :

```
ni source -i "SymbolicLink" -ta "destination" //new items -ta (target) -i (ItemType )
```